# How can I have MySQL persist on CoreOS Updates?

Tags: mysql, docker, coreos

I am looking to have an app that i'm building running on a CoreOS cluster. When CoreOS updates itself, it has to restart for a short period of time while installing the updates/switching partitions. My question is how can I keep MySQL "alive" when updating the operating system? I'm guessing this is achieved through some sort of cluster configuration? But what happens when the master goes down? I have been googling this to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad topic. I would suggest you take a look at [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html). This enables you to restart a machine without loosing access to MySQL.

MySQL replication enables you to run MySQL on multiple servers in a way that if one of them goes down, the rest take over. In case master instance is unavailable [mysqlfailover](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqlfailover.html) enables you to execute failover to the best slave available.